# Cannot start docker engine daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I get these results trying to start the daemon (Ubuntu 20.04). Suggestions appreciated:

```
andrew@andrew-VirtualBox:~$ sudo dockerd
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.047977041-05:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.055612067-05:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.090558541-05:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.090596347-05:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.090620752-05:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.090669859-05:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.147449136-05:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.147512062-05:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.147533188-05:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.147653426-05:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2022-09-12T21:05:16.586351797-05:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to ran

```
ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh
```

and then start it with

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: I did this (it is one  answer already on stackoverflow). It did not work.